# Using third party dll 4.0 to .net project 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have a working project built .NET with a target framework of 3.5 and using 2.0 dlls.

I want to add 2 third party dlls (BPOINT) to my Class library Project(DAL) with a run-time version of 4.0.30319 but I cant build the project after i reference it.

I did have a search around and tried a few suggestions but couldnt get it work.
[Can .NET 4.0 code interoperate with .NET 2.0 code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647197/can-net-4-0-code-interoperate-with-net-2-0-code)
I added in the code in the app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

But it didn't seem to work when I tried rebuilding it.
Should the above code be the first child of the  tag?

I made sure that my local machine has .net framework 4 installed.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:9/11/2016

I have decided to target the project (DAL) to framework ASP.NET 4.5 and update any references if needed.

Just a question, asp.net 4.5 supports all libraries from asp.net 3.5 CLR?

Comment: Look into this post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/05/30/how-to-use-a-net-4-based-dll-from-net-2-based-application/

Comment: I did have a look at that as well using COM but was hoping for a simpler solution.