# Any harm in changing a void return type to something else in a commonly used utility function?

Tags: c#

if I have a function like

```
public void usefulUtility(parameters...) { 
    string c = "select * from myDB";
    do_a_database_call(c);
}
```

that's used in alot of places, is there any possible harm in changing it to:

```
public bool usefulUtility(parameters...) { 
   string c = "select * from myDB";
   bool result = do_a_database_call(c);
   return result;
}
```

Could this possibly break any code?

I can't think of anything... but it may be possible?

Comment: [Yes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change.aspx)

Comment: The article referenced by Servy is technically correct, but going from a `void` return type to a `string` return type would not break your customer's code.

Comment: @jp2code Yes, actually, it could.  See the answer I've written up.  The article doesn't use that as one of it's examples, but it does assert that any public change is a breaking change.

Comment: Looks like anthonybell has revised the wording. By definition this would be a breaking change, but for the sake of his code he would run into no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, virtually anything that you could possibly do that affects your public interface is a breaking change.  It could be small enough that you don't care, and that nobody, or almost nobody, will actually happen to hit the corner cases, but Eric Lippert [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change.aspx) that there are edge cases (many of which involve Type inference) that can cause even these seemingly innocuous changes to break.

For your particular example, this code would be broken by that change.

```
Action a = usefulUtility;
```

Comment: But his original version returned `null`, so you would have no way to assign `a` with the original version. Correct?

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one who keeps a catalog of Lippert's posts in my head. @jp2code in this case, he's not calling the usefulUtility method, he's saving it as a delegate to the Action method, which would break because the delegate definition has changed.

Comment: @jp2code This code will work just fine with a void return type.  It will not compile after being changed to return a string.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I had the same thought.

Comment: why won't it compile?  the original code (that calls usefulUtility) would call the function not expecting a return value, and would continue to do so.

Comment: @anthonybell `usefulUtility` isn't being called at all here.  The definition of the method is being assigned to a delegate.  `Action` is a delegate that takes no parameters and returns `void`.  Changing the definition of the method to take parameters, or not return `void` will prevent it from compiling.  (It's easiest to just try to compile it yourself to see.)

Comment: ohh i see. a delegate needs an exact signiture and this could be a potential problem if someone's delegate is using this function.

Answer (score 2):

A change like this could definitely break stuff, both in terms of binary compatibility and in terms of source compatibility.

You might want to have a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472967/184630) and its associated thread, where API-breaking changes are discussed in depth.

Comment: Ah! I see a reference to a delegate in your link. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly *possible* that it could break some other code. As Lippert points out, nearly [Every public change is a breaking change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change.aspx) in some bizarre situation.

The more important question is, is it *likely* to cause anything to break, and the answer is no. You should be pretty safe making this change, because people aren't likely to do the bizarre kinds of things they would have to do for this to cause problems. That doesn't mean it's impossible to break some other code, but it's outside the realm of reasonable responsibility.

Comment: It's worth noting that impact is also a function of how used your library is (in addition to likeliness).  For a BCL method even very, very unlikely circumstances still come up, sometimes quite a lot in terms of absolute numbers.  If it's a library only used on a handful of projects within your company, even likely cases may not come up at all.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to actually return a String or at least null for the method to compile. You could no longer end the method without a return.

Comment: I assume he means in terms of, "Is this a breaking change to my clients if this is a library function?".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be absolutely sure of not breaking anything, give the method that returns a String a different name, and leave the void method signature the same.