# What is a breaking change in software?

Tags: architecture

In our company we have a definition of what a breaking change is and we try to avoid it as much as possible.

It is a change

```
 - that changes a method signature.
 - that changes the behavior of a method.
 - that changes settings, configuration.
 - that adds dependencies to a module, assembly etc..
```

Would you say this is a good/complete definition of a breaking change? Is there something missing? Would you consider a change in the database schema a breaking change too (e.g. a new column or new table)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Just found this [A definitive guide to API-breaking changes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456785/a-definitive-guide-to-api-breaking-changes-in-net)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more a conceptual question about software development and as such will better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: check this https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first point is to decide what "breaking change" means in English*. In some places it would be merely something which stops the code from compiling / running.

From your list so far, I suppose you mean a change that will require other people to make a corresponding change. In that case, since each module of your product should have a well defined interface (be it to other modules, a public REST interface, the system's filesystem, a gui, a webapp, etc), then a breaking change is anything that *removes* something from one of those interfaces (or adds a new *requirement* for their use) - in effect, **if you cannot take the previous version of the product and swap *just* the module with the change in, then it is a breaking one**.

So, yes, database changes will typically be breaking changes (unless there is code to auto-upgrade and possibly auto-downgrade as required).

The main point is what is not a breaking change - changes within a module or to undocumented interfaces (i.e. ones that should not be used) are not breaking changes. If such things do break your product then there is a failure of encapsulation.

*or your (human) language of choice.

Comment: An excellent summary. I would add to this that it is valuable for everyone to understand why there needs to be a classification of changes according to this definition. A typical scenario could be that you have licensed your software product to a third-party, and that they are concerned with any updates that you provide them with. Is the update a drop-in replacement? Or will it drive a lot of extra development and verification work? If you can answer the question as to why it is important to define what a breaking change is, the definition as such should be pretty easy to work out.

Comment: so the "breaking" in bootstrap 5 documentation means, it is a breaking change right ?