# r version 4.3.0 ggplot not working in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a Shiny app which has worked perfectly for a number of years. I recently upgraded linux (ubuntu) and all associated apps using the standard apt-get update/upgrade syntax which left me running ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded R from 4.0.0 to 4.3.0.

Now (having updated a number of associated libraries), the plots on my app aren't displaying. The
same code runs and displays perfectly on my macbook (still running R 4.0.2).

I have checked the logs and no log file is generated suggesting that, as far as R is concerned, the
code is executing (and exiting) normally.

I have followed the instructions in this post

[Accessing Error log in shiny-server deployed on AWS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377437/accessing-error-log-in-shiny-server-deployed-on-aws-instance)

in order to get additional error logging - but this also shows no errors are being identified.

Have others seen this with R 4.3.0 and ggplot ? if so is it reasonable to simply roll
back to an earlier version of R ?? - I would point out that I don't know how to do a roll
back so any help in that regard would be very welcome

Peter

Comment: I assume you have checked that your packages (namely `ggplot2` and `shiny`) are updated? Have you tried looking at breaking changes for either packages, or reading the major release notes for the R>4.0?

Comment: Thanks for your response gowest - yes I have updated ggplota and shiny, and read the release notes ... not sure what you are referring to with "breaking changes" - haven't heard that expression before.

Comment: Hi Peter! See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703216/what-is-a-breaking-change-in-software) or [this wikitionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change). As a silly example, imagine if `ggplot2` deprecated the use of `aes()` and you have to use `aesth`. Anyone who was running old code on the new version of ggplot2 would get an error. The same goes if base-R undergoes a back-end change which messes with something you wrote. You can see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/#breaking-changes for some recent breaking changes.

Comment: While reading all of the breaking changes could be cumbersome, you could also just intall and require that an older version of `ggplot2` and `shiny` are used. That assumes this actually the issue, and that the versions you were using at the time work in your new R installation. If not, you could also run it on an old version of R entirely. This could end up being more work than it's worth, if this might not even be the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your response (and the link) gowest. I have the same app on my Macbook (R4.0.0) and it runs properly - just not on the ubuntu R 4.3.2 (which is available across the whole network). Both Macbook and ubuntu have ggplot 2 v 3.4.2 installed that's why I think it's the combination of R 4.3.0 and ggplot 3.4.2 that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - after weeks of trying I noticed that the privileges of the /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ directory had been changed to prevent writing to it (possibly in the ubuntu upgrade process or (more likely) in the R upgrade process - 4.0.0 to 4.3.0). Resetting the privileges for the directory solved the problem.