# Should I use an implicit conversion to my return type, to aid in debugging?

Tags: c#, standards, implicit-conversion, return-type

I have the following method in my API

```
 public bool CheckSignature(string data, string key)
 { ... }
```

In the event that I return false (for an invalid signature), I'd like the ability to cleanly get the debug data without changing all my callers code.

If I was returning an object, I would simply add a debug type like this

```
public class SignatureResult
{
     public bool Validation {get;set;}
     public SpecialDebugObject Debug {get;set;}
}
```

- Is it a bad idea for me to change my API so that it returns a `SignatureResult` but with an implicit conversion to bool so the existing clients don't break?
- Would this be OK to do for a new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing clients *will* break, this is a breaking change.

The code written against `CheckSignature` expects a `bool` to be returned. Even if there's an implicit conversion between your type and bool, the compiled IL is missing the proper conversion instruction.

This is analogous to changing a field to be a property instead: [you lose binary compatibility](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx).

> Would this be OK to do for a new API?

I wouldn't. You're exposing debugging logic.

---

Here's a good guide for what's considered a breaking change in .NET: [A definitive guide to API-breaking changes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456785/857807). As you can see, method signatures are very sensible. Changing the return type, and even the argument's *names* are considered breaking changes.