# What is the purpose of auto-implemented properties if they are treated the same as public fields (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand private fields in C#. Coming from a Java background, I am just a little confused.

Here is my class:

```
   class Student
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public int x = 6;

        public Student() // Empty constructor
        { }

        public Student(int age, string name)
        {
            Age = age; // Work with Age as it is a field
            Name = "John"; // OK: accessing a private setter
        }
    }
```

The auto-implemented properties `Age` and `Name` both can be accessed the same way the public `x` can be accessed. I can write `student.x`, just as I can write `student.Age`.

I know that the compiler creates the private fields for `Age` and `Name`, but since I can access it the same as the `x`, how is this private?

In Java, you have to call a public method that returns the private field, but with C#, it just seems like this defeats the purpose of a private field.

Basically, how does this benefit us at all? Why not just make everything public if we are going to set public setters and getters on `Age` and `Name` anyways? Logically, I just don't see the benefit or how this is actually private?

Comment: Properties are just syntax over methods.  You can do `public int X { get { <Code here that returns an int>} set { <Do something with the passed in value> }}` and then you can do something like `obj.X++;` whereas with methods you'd have to do `obj.SetX(obj.GetX()++);`  so it gives you a better experience while still keeping the backing fields private so you can add any implementation you want while maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but still feels weird. When you say `while still keeping the backing fields private`, it still seems like the backing field is public because it is directly connected to the public getter/setter.

Comment: Please look up computed properties, properties can have logic inside them and they are used for Databinding in WPF, there are many application for properties while field will just hold the value for you and does nothing.

Comment: @mastercooler6 For auto properties there is a hidden private backing field created automatically.  This was done to get rid of a bunch of boiler plate code when all you want is to set and get from a private backing field.

Comment: @mastercooler6: The point is that you can (a) change your auto-property to a "regular" property and then (b) replace the backing field with something else *without changing the signature of your class*. You can't do that with a public field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public int Age {get; set;}
```

is equivilent to

```
private int _age;
public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; }
```

Isn't the first easier to write? Doesn't it follow the same best practices from Java?

And you can also use the `private set` or `init set` to lock them down easily. I think it saves lots of typing and makes it easy to modify the get/set command latter if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, how does this benefit us at all?

Initially, it doesn't. But it allows you to create a stable API:

Imagine that, at some point in the future, you want to change the way `Age` works. You decide that you no longer want to internally store the age of a person, but rather their *birth date* and calculate the age instead. Or you want to create a log entry every time the `Age` property is accessed.

If `Age` is a field, you are out of luck. But if `Age` is an auto-implemented property, you can just change it to a "regular" property, make your desired changes in the getter and then ship an updated version of your library **without breaking backwards compatibility**, since that modification is neither [a source-level break nor a binary-level break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456785/87698). Your clients can just replace the old version of your library with the new one without having to recompile their applications. (Changing a field to a property would always be a binary-level breaking change and, in some cases, also a source-level breaking change.)